# extending _remap function codeigniter in hooks or MY_Controller

Tags: hook, codeigniter-3, remap

i have a codeigniter application that use HMVC, but for Authentication i have a Controller Auth.php, that i put it in a base Codeigniter Controller Folder not in the module folder of HMVC.

i'm using this remap function only on controller in module folder. In every module controller there is this code.

```
public function _remap($method) {
    $segment = $this->uri->segment(4);
    switch ($method) {
      case 'view':
        if($segment === 'create') {
          $this->create_view();
        } elseif($segment === 'update') {
          $this->update_view();
        } else {
          $this->search_view();
        }
        break;
      case 'process':
       if($segment === 'create') {
          $this->create_process();
        } elseif($segment === 'update') {
          $this->update_process();
        } else {
          $this->delete_process();
        }
        break;
      default:
        $this->main_view();
        break;
    }
  }
```

the question is, how can i remove this code in every module controller? I'm testing to puth the code using MY_Controller extending MX_Controller. Is Working, but in my Auth.php that extending CI_Controller is error. I have been testing using hooks, but with no luck. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

already find the answer! Just chance MY_Controller name into something else and it works.